# Mako link to current page with extra GET params

Tags: python, get, mako

Currently using Mako templates for a search engine on a Django site, and I'm pretty new to Mako templates, so forgive me if this is a silly question, but it seems that this particular aspect doesn't line up with the DTL implementation and I'm kind of at a loss. Basically I have a get request coming in and I want to generate some links to the current page with added GET parameters. Currently I just have the query, but I would like this interface to be RESTful and very linkable so I would prefer to keep this as a long GET request rather than switching to a POST.

This is my current code, which doesn't quite work and seems quite inelegant:

```
<a href="${request.path}&page=${ data.next_page_number() }">Next</a>
```

The meaning of request.path seems to be slightly different in Mako than in DTL, so `request.path` doesn't include any of the original GET parameters. Any help on either a better way to go about this or a solution to this implementation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no "meaning" for request.path in Mako because Mako is not a language. If you want you request object to be available in Mako, pass it as parameter when rendering the page.

Comment: I passed in `request.path` from Python, but I left it like this since scope isn't the issue here. However, `${request.path}` Doesn't actually include the parameters passed to it. Is there a different attribute of the request I should use instead?